# Posting html from form to data extension via ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, form, cloudpage

Hi I have a form on a cloud page. Among other fields, there is a text area in which my customer wants to put text and simple html like `<br>`

The form is posting to another cloud page where some ssjs sends the data into a data extension.

Now I get an error everytime there is a `<br>` in the text. The form doesn't post at all. Any ideas on how to solve?

In the form:

```
<textarea class="white-input area" name="e_bodytext" placeholder="Body
text">%%=v(@e_bodytext)=%%</textarea>
```

In the serverside js-file:

```
e_bodytext: Request.GetFormField('e_bodytext')
```

The field in the data extension is text and lets me store 3000 characters

Comment: Posting the error would be helpful

Comment: I solved it replacing all <br> with \n before I posted the form. Then in receiving cloudpage I turned all \n back to <br> before I sent it along to the data extension. Using regex in both cases.